# Chained form fill in django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django model

**Models.py**

```
class ReceiveDocket(models.Model):
    sender_parent_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender_parent_client')
    client_location = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_location')
    received_at_warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='warehouse_list')


class Client(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    client_company = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    client_shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
```

and a form of receive docket:

[image]

**Views.py**

```
@method_decorator([login_required, employee_required], name='dispatch')
class ReceiveDocketFormView(CreateView):
    model = ReceiveDocket
    fields = "__all__"
    template_name = 'packsapp/employee/docketRecievedForm.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'The Docket was created with success!')
        return redirect('employee:docket_table')
```

How can I change my views such that when I select the sender parent client it automatically fills the client address in `client location` or at least show the client address in the drop-down ?

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for [How to Implement Dependent/Chained Dropdown List with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: Actually Chained dropdown done in the given link is done from two different models i.e. Country and City but in my case the data in both fields are coming from same model

Answer (score 0):

The selection is done in the template, so any changes to enable this functionality start with decisions to be made there.

You have two potential ways to do this

**1. With an Ajax Call**

This has already been mentioned in the comments, but here is a [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) tutorial on how to implement this. This is the better way to do this, but is admittedly a bit more complex than the alternative.

**2. Because it is the same model, you could potentially use pure front-end Javascript**

This is dependent on the number of options for the dropdown being fairly reasonable and there being only one address per client. You could implement the form manually in the template and add something like this to your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/" id="carform">
</form>
<select name="countrylist" form="carform" class="first" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="none" selected>-----</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="uk">UK</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
</select>
<select name="capitallist2" form="carform" class="second" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="none" selected>-----</option>
  <option value="canada">Ottawa</option>
  <option value="usa">Washington</option>
  <option value="uk">London</option>
  <option value="france">Paris</option>
</select>

<input form="carform" type="submit">

<script>
function myFunction() {
   $(".second").val($(".first").val());
}
</script>
```

You would just fill in the `<select>` in both cases with a for loop.